# построение "прерывистого" графика с помощью matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, визуализация

Подскажите пожалуйста, как с помощью `matplotlib` построить прерывистый график.
Вот код:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y=[0, 20, 20, 0, 0, 0, 20, 20, 20, 20]
x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Необходимо, чтобы получился прерывистый график в виде горизонтальной прямой, т. е. на участках, когда `y = 0` график не рисовался. Понимаю, что `plot` соединяет точки. Не смог найти в документации на `matplotlib` возможность построения прерывистого графика. Возможно это реализуется с использованием `numpy`. Буду рад любому совету. Спасибо!

Comment: Вам нужна функция [`step`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.step.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените нули на `None`, например, так:

```
plt.plot(x, [i or None for i in y])
```

`Matplotlib` пропускает значения `None` как-раз так, как вам нужно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: CrazyElf - огромное человеческое СПАСИБО!! Вы в очередной раз меня очень выручили! Спасибо!